# Bash exec a loop

Tags: bash

I'm learning exec by passing it a loop, but the following does not work

```sh
$exec while true\; do\; sleep 100\; done
exits immediately
```

== update ==

Charles explained in the comment that you can't.

> `exec` replaces the shell with a different executable. while is not an executable, so exec can't run it; instead, it's shell syntax -- there has to be a shell there to run it, so it can't happen after your shell exited (unless you're just replacing your shell with a different shell, and telling that shell to run the loop -- this is that Glenn's answer does).

Comment: Why do you expect `exec` to be the right tool to use in this context at all? It forces the current shell to _exit immediately_, replacing itself with another executable; whereas a `while` loop is a shell command -- it can only run _inside_ a shell.

Comment: ...whereas `while true; do sleep 100; done` is not an executable at all, so it's normal for an attempt to `exec` it to fail.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the operation being attempted is not semantically meaningful, and the question does not describe the intent of the operation (to allow an alternative means of accomplishing that attempt to be suggested instead).

Comment: Hi Charles. I'm learning bash now, and I'm asking if I can ask `exec` to execute a loop. I don't see how my question lack intent. It seems a valid question that a curious mind would ask.

Comment: Why can't `while` be executed when it is a shell command by definition? I'm not very familiar with the definitions you gave.

Comment: `exec` replaces the shell with a different executable. `while` is not an executable, so `exec` can't run it; instead, it's shell syntax -- there has to be a shell there to run it, so it can't happen after your shell exited (unless you're just replacing your shell with a _different shell_, and telling _that_ shell to run the loop -- this is that Glenn's answer does).

Comment: To explain what I meant above: "Ask exec to execute a loop" does not describe something the computer can actually do with enough clarity to be a meaningful question. If you went into what you meant to _accomplish_ by doing that, we could tell you what could be done instead, but right now the question doesn't tell us what you're trying to accomplish by doing this, so we can't tell you how to accomplish that end goal only by means that are actually possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to force a multi-line command, use another shell:

```sh
exec sh -c 'while true; do echo sleeping; sleep 1; done'
```